# GoogleTest not working on path with jp characters

Tags: c++, windows, googletest

When running my test application for windows on path with JP characters, it fails to call the function **ASSERT_EXIT(myTestFunction(testCase), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "")**. When called the **myTestFunction(testCase)** without using ASSERT_EXIT(), the function is invoked.

Here is the original code where the function call fails,

```
TEST_P(Transponder, startReplaying)
{
    std::string testCase = (std::string)GetParam();
    ASSERT_EXIT(myTestFunction(testCase), ::testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "");
}
```

I got to know ASSERT_EXIT is called via subprocess. Any leads on how to handle multibyte strings when called via subprocess for googletest?

Comment: `std::string testCase = (std::string)GetParam();` -- Why the cast?  Remove the cast to `std::string` and simply call `GetParam()`.  Recompile.  What are the compiler errors (if any)?

Comment: I printed the string and the strings are correct. The problem is, myTestFunction isn't invoked. There isn't any compiler errors or run time errors.